# Citing quotes/footnotes

Tags: quotes, chicago-manual-of-style, footnotes

In my memoir, I use several quotations. In the text, I note who said them: e.g.

> As author and diplomat Washington Irving, having mourned a fiancée and a brother, wrote: 'There is a sacredness in tears...'

I'm using Chicago-style formatting. Do I also have to include a footnote and/or bibliography item saying where I found this quotation?

Answer (score 1):

You should include both the citation and a footnote ([Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/chicago_manual_17th_edition/cmos_formatting_and_style_guide/chicago_manual_of_style_17th_edition.html)). In Chicago style formatting ([17th ed.](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html)):

> Author Names

The author’s name is inverted in the bibliography, placing the last name first and separating the last name and first name with a comma.

> Titles

Titles of books and journals are italicized. Titles of articles, chapters, poems, etc. are placed in quotation marks.

> Publication Information

The year of publication is listed after the publisher or journal name.

> Punctuation

In a bibliography, all major elements are separated by periods.